# React with TypeScript: What type is render()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to convert my components to TypeScript. What type can I specify for render, which returns HTML?

```
class Component extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                ...some HTML...
            </div>
        );       
    }
}
```

Comment: public render(): React.ReactNode

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't know whether it did when this question was first asked, but React has types available via the `@types/react` module (now). The return type of `render` is `React.ReactNode` which is defined like this:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

You can find the details of those various subtypes in the [`index.d.ts` file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts) at [`DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped).

> Can I specify any type for render, which returns HTML?

`render` doesn't return HTML (which would be a string). From [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render):

> When called, it should examine this.props and this.state and return one of the following types:
>
> - **React elements**. Typically created via JSX. For example, `<div />` and `<MyComponent />` are React elements that instruct React to render a DOM node, or another user-defined component, respectively.
> - **Arrays and fragments**. Let you return multiple elements from render. See the documentation on fragments for more details.
> - **Portals**. Let you render children into a different DOM subtree. See the documentation on portals for more details.
> - **String and numbers**. These are rendered as text nodes in the DOM.
> - **Booleans or null**. Render nothing. (Mostly exists to support `return test && <Child />` pattern, where test is boolean.)

Comment: Oh, so it doesn't return HTML. Thanks!

Comment: There has been some change, now the documentation indicates more stuff possibly returned.

Comment: @unludo - Thanks. There are full types available for it now, too. (If there weren't before; there might have been.)